# WSO2 BAM Gadget Generation

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I created a gadget using WSO2 Gadget Generation Tool. I did everything successfully, and I could see my bar graph at the end. I created my gadget url.

Now, when I add Gadget to Dashboard, I see only blank box and no graph.

Console shows the following error:
[2013-02-25 11:05:18,837] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dashboard.mgt.gadgetrepo.ui.Gad
getRepoUiUtils} -  unknown protocol: local

I get this exception as soon as I click on Add Gadget Button!

Please help me. What m I doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your url is malformed. It usually is something that is starting with `http://localhost:9763` followed by the path. But it seems when you are copy-pasting something has gone wrong. Fix the url and it should work.

Comment: Hi Tharindu,

my url formed is http:// localhost :9763/registry/resource/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.bam.gadgetgen/gadgetgen/ems-resource.xml

I tried pasting this url only... but its not working for me...

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I had put it (spaces) to paste link here on stackoverflow... it wasnt allowing me to paste otherwise...

Comment: In the left-hand menu, there will be a registry -> browse option. Can you have a look whether your gadget xml is there at '/_system/config/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.bam‌​.gadgetgen/gadgetgen/ems-resource.xml'. If so, the gadget is successfully generated. Maybe you can try from another browser as well. I double checked and this just works for me.